# Render angular2 component from a variable

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application

Let's say I have a component `Field` and have in a `Main` component I have an instance of `Field` like:

```
export class MainComponent {
    public field = new Field("my field value ");
    ...
```

How can I display that field in this component's html ?

Comment: What is the `Field` component look like?

Comment: @yurzui I want to make different input fields they are usually something like `<input type="?">` or sometimes like a `div` with some inputs and a button for uploading images. I am trying to make something like admin-on-rest but using angular2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 is an example that uses it via`ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`